# Using jQuery to set the size of a new window

Tags: jquery

I am opening a link in a new window using jQuery:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href="/education/global-health-courses"]').attr("target", "_blank");    
});
</script>
```

I would like to set the size of the new window to 800px wide by 700px tall. I just need a little help adding those attributes to the existing code.

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can't set those attributes using the `target="_blank"` method, you have to use the window.open method:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a[href="/education/global-health-courses"]').click(function() {
        window.open($(this).attr('href'),'title', 'width=800, height=700');
        return false;
    });   
});
```

Comment: @fmz: you can find all the options of the window.open method here: http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml

Answer (score 1):

You can't resize a `target=blank` window AFAIK.

You will have to create a new one using `window.open` - outlined e.g. in [**this article**](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) - and add a `testwindow.resizeTo(x,y)` command to make sure.

Answer (score 1):

a nice way to do this would to use an iframe with colorbox (http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/)

```
$('a[href="/education/global-health-courses"]')
   .colorbox({width:"80%", height:"80%", iframe:true});
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to set the window size you need to use [window.open](http://www.javascript-coder.com/window-popup/javascript-window-open.phtml) method. Instead of using `target="_blank"` on the anchor you could subscribe to the `click` event and call `window.open`.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want very fine control of the look and behaviour, i strongly recommand the use of a script called [ShadowBox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/). It's the most stable and versatile modal window javascript script. You can launch external pages inside a popup div (containing an iframe) with that script.