# How can I target a new window being opened to specify the size of it?

Tags: jquery

And I don't mean the millions of questions already asked about how to open in a new window and how to specify the size. I mean, I've already got a link that opens a page in a new window. Instead of having to add an onclick to the link, is it possible to, in an external JavaScript file, to detect the new window to specify the size? Or if the external is attached to the new window then it specifies the size when it loads or something?

I did take this tidbit:

```
$('a[href="/education/global-health-courses"]').click(function() {
        window.open($(this).attr('href'),'title', 'width=800, height=700');
        return false;
});
```

From this answer: [Using jQuery to set the size of a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096363/using-jquery-to-set-the-size-of-a-new-window)

And applied it to my code in attempt to get something working:

```
$('a[href="DisiplineDrawings/Compliance/cadfiles/compliance-ada-03.html"]').click(function() {
        window.open($(this).attr('width=800, height=700'));
        return false;
    });
```

Here is the HTML involved:

```
<a href="DisciplineDrawings/Compliance/cadfiles/compliance-ada-03.html" class="btn btn-primary block-center hidden-xs hidden-sm ">CAD</a>
```

I was hoping then that the return:false; in the JS would prevent that link from being followed? I think that's similar to the scenario in the link I gave?

Answer (score 2):

You could do it with native javascript directly in your html:

```
<a onclick="window.open('DisciplineDrawings/Compliance/cadfiles/compliance-ada-03.html','CAD','width=800,height=700')" href="javascript: void(0)">CAD</a>
```

The same thing in your jQuery code should look like this:

```
$('a[href="DisiplineDrawings/Compliance/cadfiles/compliance-ada-03.html"]').click(function() {
    window.open($(this).attr('href'), 'CAD', 'width=800, height=700');
    return false;
});
```

The way "window.open" is built is like this: "window.open(url, title, attributes);"
But in your example you left out the "url" which it obviously needs.

Hope that helps!

Comment: You obviously didn't read my question. The question you answered has already been answered a dozen times. I don't want to touch my HTML.

Comment: I'm sorry, but if you look at my answer once more, you'll see that I also gave you the jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

I think that in the new opened window you will have access to `window.opener`. By using it you can know if the new window is opened by another window or it is opened in a new tab/window by the user. So it answers your question "Or if the external is attached to the new window then it specifies the size when it loads or something?" The rest is up to how you want to resize the new opened window